# How to make full screen gradient color in IntroductionScreen widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in Flutter. i want to make full screen gradient background color use IntroductionScreen widget. however, when i use gradient color in box decoration there is white box space in the bottom. I don't want that to happen. This is my code

```
return IntroductionScreen(
  pages: [
    PageViewModel(
      title: "Hallo1",
      body:
          "Instead of having to buy an entire share, invest any amount you want.",
      image: buildImage('assets/onboard1bg.png'),
      decoration: buildDecoration(),
    ),
    PageViewModel(
      title: "Hallo2",
      body:
          "Instead of having to buy an entire share, invest any amount you want.",
      image: buildImage('assets/onboard2bg.png'),
      decoration: buildDecoration(),
    ),
  ],
  showNextButton: false,
  showDoneButton: false,
  showSkipButton: false,
  dotsDecorator: getDotDecoration(),
  globalFooter: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(
            'Login',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            CupertinoModalBottom(context, "Login", SignIn(), true);
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
            primary: Colors.orange,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }

  DotsDecorator getDotDecoration() => DotsDecorator(
        color: Colors.grey,
        size: Size(15, 8),
        activeColor: Colors.white,
        activeSize: Size(25, 8),
        activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
      );

  Widget buildImage(String path) => Center(child: Image.asset(path));

  PageDecoration buildDecoration() => PageDecoration(
        imagePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        boxDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(205, 193, 255, 1.0),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 79, 10),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 31, 31),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

and this is how it looks, i want to make gradient color full screen. but, didn't work

[image]

Comment: could you please include your IntroductionScreen class?

Comment: i use this library https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to remove the white box because [it's hardcoded in the `introduction_screen` source code](https://github.com/Pyozer/introduction_screen/blob/9e336aea51e43319ebcee4b8dd0c1c928392b0ec/lib/src/ui/intro_page.dart#L66).

But there's a workaround. Just wrap the `IntroductionScreen` with a `Stack` and set its `globalBackgroundColor` to `Colors.transparent`. Remove the decoration from the `PageViewModel`s. Then, add a `Container` with the desired decoration as the first widget in the `Stack` to serve as the background. It's going to look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code snippet:

```dart
return Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(205, 193, 255, 1.0),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 79, 10),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 31, 31),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    IntroductionScreen(

    ...
```